# Excel Macro For Counting Matching Data

Tags: vba, date, excel, count

I need a macro for counting the number of specific dates and then enter that amount next to each date.   For example, I need excel to do the following:

```
Column A Column B

1/1/2014 5
1/1/2014 5
1/1/2014 5
1/1/2014 5
1/1/2014 5
1/2/2014 3
1/2/2014 3
1/2/2014 3
1/3/2014 4
1/3/2014 4
1/3/2014 4
1/3/2014 4
```

It needs to count how many times the date appears and enter it next to every matching cell.  There are 5 times 1/1/14 is listed, so it needs 5 entered in the B column every time 1/1/14 is listed.   And there are 3 times 1/2/14 is listed, so a 3 needs to be entered next to those dates in the B column...etc, etc...

Any suggestions for a macro that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA, you can use simple formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

just write it in `B1` and drag it down.

---

But if VBA is requared, you can use this simple code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    With Range("B1:B" & lastrow)
        .Formula = "=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)"
        .Calculate
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```